# Stripe : New customer created even when customer_id is not empty?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to retrieve my user's existing cards from Stripe with the below code. That said, when I use the below backend, even though I'm telling Stripe to ONLY create a new customer if $customer_id is NOT present, a new customer ID is created anyway even when customer_id is NOT null? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here...

**.php**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$customer_id = $_POST['customer_id']; //get this id from somewhere a database table, post parameter, etc.
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  'email' => $email, 

));

$customer_id = $_POST['customer_id']; //get this id from somewhere a database table, post parameter, etc.

// if the customer id doesn't exist create the customer
if ($customer_id !== null) {

    $key = \Stripe\EphemeralKey::create(
      ["customer" => $customer->id],
      ["stripe_version" => $_POST['api_version']]
    );

      header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit(json_encode($key));

} else {

//  \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id);

    $cards = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id)->sources->all(); 
    // return the cards

      header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit(json_encode($key));
}
```

Comment: what does this have to do with either `ios` or `obj-c` ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Sorry, old habit. Front end is obj-c; used to putting it in the tags!

Comment: `$customer_id` probably contains something that's empty but not null, like zero or empty string.

Comment: You are creating the customer at the top (without any conditions) - Why isn't `\Stripe\Customer::create`  in the null check block? If you wrap the `\Stripe\Customer::create` call in your `if ($customer_id !== null) {` block, does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IF condition should we switched around. Currently you create a customer if the `customer_id` is present. Based on the description you'd like to see the opposite, right?

In this case all you'd need to do is to switch around the if / else bodies:

```
if ($customer_id !== null) {
  $cards = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id)->sources->all(); 
  // return the cards
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  exit(json_encode($cards)); // you might want to return the cards here?
} else {
  $key = \Stripe\EphemeralKey::create(
    ["customer" => $customer->id],
    ["stripe_version" => $_POST['api_version']]
  );

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  exit(json_encode($key));
}
```

AND remove the create block at the top. That will create a customer object as well, which you don't need.